# If certain characters then add comma

Tags: string, excel, vba, character

I need a macro to find characters that are as follows: "Uppercase""Lowercase""Uppercase"

I have tried this with:

```
If character like "[A-Z]", "[a-z]", "[A-Z]" then......
```

with parenthesis in different spots and it would not work.

please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you please make an example? If I had understood, you want to find the sequence "AcK" in "StAcKoverflow", isn't it? What you want to do with this substring? Remove it, store it or what else? Please detail your question.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @MatteoNNZ it would be if AcK then Ac,K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be okay to use formula?

```
=IF (  AND    (ISNUMBER(FIND((MID(B4,1,1)),$D$4,1)),
               ISNUMBER(FIND((MID(B4,2,1)),$D$5,1)),
               ISNUMBER(FIND((MID(B4,3,1)),$D$4,1))                       
              ),
       "True",
       "False")
```

where 
      cell B4 contains your text under test, e,g, "AcK"

```
  cell D4 contains the string "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

  cell D5 contains the string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Comment: @pnuts That doesnt seem to work at all. It just copies the text to the cell in which I put that formula in

Comment: @pnuts oh I didn't, but I was able to find a macro to do it. The formulas tend to slow down what I am aiming to accomplish. Thank you though

Answer (score 2):

```
? "AcK" like "[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]" '>> True

? "ACK" like "[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]" '>> False
```

Comment: not so much the second one. But the first one is what I need. So then could i just have it as If like "[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]" Then ?? add a comma in between [A-Z][a-z] and [A-Z].  
So in the end it will be [A-Z][a-z],[A-Z]

Comment: The second one is just there to demonstrate that the first one actually does work...

Comment: oh gotcha. But how would I make it be found in a cell with other words in it and separate the lowercase and second uppercase with a comma?

Comment: `If s Like "[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]" Then s = Left(s,2) & "," & Right(s,1)`

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your objective, try to include a function like this in your project:

```
Public Function editString(ByVal nativeString As String) As String

    Dim subStr As String, subStr2 As String

    For j = 1 To Len(nativeString)

        subStr = Mid(nativeString, j, 3)
        If subStr Like "[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]" Then
            subStr2 = Left(subStr, 2) & "," & Right(subStr, 1)
            nativeString = Replace(nativeString, subStr, subStr2)
        End If

    Next j

    editString = nativeString

End Function
```

...then modify the string objects by simply passing them into the function:

```
Public Sub ModifyString()
    Dim newString As String: newString = editString("stAcKoverflow")
End Sub
```

You should get what you want.